# Stop Docker container in Jenkins if job aborted/timed out

Tags: docker, jenkins

We have a number of jobs where we use docker container do do stuff. Sometimes these jobs time out or are aborted and I need to make sure the docker containers are properly shut down.

I tried to add in the "execute shell" step, a trap

```
function stop_container() {
  docker stop `cat docker.cid`
}

trap stop_container TERM EXIT

docker run --cidfile docker.cid ...
```

But nothing happens. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use post-build actions similar to the following.

[image]

Comment: and how do I get Jenkins to know the container id?

Comment: You could set the container name when you create it to be something unique and deterministic like $BUILD_NAME

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is just fine if you setup your job from the ui.
Incase your job is created with a pipeline then you will need to surround the whole pipeline with

```java
    try{
        node{
        //steps
        }
    }
    catch{
     //do whatever you like
    }
    finally{
      docker.stopContainer()
    }
```

This applies to scripted pipelines. Note that pressing stop at the run throws an `InterruptedException` in the pipeline. If you press it multiple times it may skip the `finally` block also.

If your pipeline is not scripted and is declarative you can put a post-step that will do the same as before ( its the same as the UI )

Last but not least it may help you as jenkins support docker agents that may be useful depending on your case.
[Docker agents for jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

[Declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-pipeline-fundamentals)

[Post stage for declarative](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post)

[Scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals)